# using url helper issue in laravel 5

Tags: url, laravel, helper

i'd set up a new route

```
Route::get('/posts/{slug}', [
        'as'=>'postshow',
        'uses'=>'PostController@getShow'
    ]);
```

i also created a controller:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
        public function getShow($slug)
        {
            return view($slug);
        }
}
```

and i implemented it in the home.blade.phpin which i'm using the url helper :

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('content')

    @if($posts->count())
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <article>
                <h2><a href="{{$url=action('postshow',$post->slug)}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h2>
                    {!!Markdown::parse(str_limit($post->body, $limit=250, $end="..."))!!}
                <a href="">Read more &arr; </a>
            </article>
        @endforeach
    @endif

@stop
```

It wokrs just fine in laravel 4, but it doesn't do the work in laravel 5. The error i get is, that the 'postshow', which i defined as i was creating route, is not defined.

> Action App\Http\Controllers\postshow not defined.

Do you have any solution to that? i'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong helper here. If you want to reference the route by it's name, use `route()`:

```
{{ $url=route('postshow',$post->slug) }}
```

If you wanted to use `action()` you'd have to pass the name of the controller and the method:

```
{{ $url=action('PostController@getShow',$post->slug) }}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer. I used the right url helper, as you've suggested, but i still can't get the return value from  'PostController.php' as i click on the link. I should get the slug value returned as i click on the link, or should i? .. thanks

Comment: Not really. With your current controller code you are trying to render a view with name of `$slug`. What you want instead is just `return $slug` to return the slug value.

Comment: I tried that too, also echoing it out, but it seems not to get through th constroller somehow. But thanks, i think that the main problem is solved.

Comment: What's the URL you see after clicking on the link?

Comment: the url is: http://localhost/laravel/public/posts/radost . the slug contains the word 'radost' so it reads the slug variable

Comment: sure, i accepted it, but anyway, do you have some thoughts on that?

Comment: just requested url not being found

Comment: Sorry I don't know what the problem could be. Good luck figuring it out :)